# Group specific HTML-tags into sections

Tags: php, html, regex, xml-parsing

I've a string with a markup like this:

```
<h3></h3>
<p><span><strong></strong></span></p>
<p></p>
<div></div>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<img />
<div></div>
```

And I want to group **all** tags into sections. But **except** divs and imgs. These both tags should be in their own section and should not be grouped together. So the result should be like this:

```
<section>
    <h3></h3>
    <p><span><strong></strong></span></p>
    <p></p>
</section>

<section>
    <div></div>
</section>

<section>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
</section>

<section>
    <img />
</section>

<section>
    <div></div>
</section>
```

How can I do this with php?

Comment: No regular expression can do this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454  Regular expressions are not the right tool for the job.  You want a XML parser.

Comment: ok, thanks. do you have any good ones for me?

Comment: I don't have any direct experience with XML parsing for PHP.  A Google search for PHP XML parsing should get you close.

Comment: [SimpleXML](http://php.net/simplexml) is what you want if using PHP.

Comment: Or [`DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the content you give is only in the body, you can use this:

```
$data = <<<'LOD'
<h3></h3>
<p><span><strong></strong></span></p>
<p></p>
<div></div>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<img />
<div></div>
<p><p><img /></p></p>
<!-- <img /> -->
<div> <div> </div> </div>
LOD;

$pattern = <<<'LOD'
~
(?(DEFINE)
    (?<comment> <!-- .*? --> )
    (?<cdata> \Q<![CDATA[\E .*? ]]> )
    (?<script_style> <s(cript|tyle)\b .*? </s\g{-1}> )
    (?<skip_list>
        \g<comment> | \g<cdata> | \g<script_style> 
    )

    (?<tag>
        <code\b .*? </code> | \g<self_closing_tag> |
        <(\w++) [^>]*+>
        (?> [^<]++ | \g<skip_list> | \g<tag> )*+
        </\g{-1}> 
    )
    (?<self_closing_tag> <(?:img|[bh]r)\b [^>]*+> )
    (?<other_tag> (?!<(?:img|div)\b) \g<tag>  )

    (?<div> (?=<div\b) \g<tag>)
    (?<img> (?=<img\b) \g<self_closing_tag>)

    (?<other_tags> \g<other_tag> (?>[^<]*+ \g<other_tag>)*+ )
)

\g<skip_list> (*SKIP)(*FAIL)
|
\g<div> | \g<img> | \g<other_tags>  

~xsi
LOD;


$result = preg_replace($pattern, "\n<section>\n$0\n</section>", $data);

echo htmlspecialchars($result);
```

Comment: Hey dude, this works like a charm. But one thing: is it possible to get it work with code tags in the html like this: `<pre><code>$hello = here_is_code();</code></pre>` ?

Comment: No, there is a div-wrapper around the pre-tags. But at the moment, the hole script isn't working with code in the code-tag.

Comment: Why does php require (?(DEFINE) .. ) before actually making a call to something? As if the group has to exist first. Perl lets you put it anywhere.

Comment: @sln: you can put it where you want in PHP too. It's only a writing convention for myself.

Comment: I ran some test code in php_sandbox site and it only worked with it at the top. Oh well, I only tried it once though. .. Btw, this is nice code!

Comment: Ah... your script works perfect. I've done a mistake. Everything ok :)

Comment: @PhilippKühn: Happy for you, but don't believe that this code is totally waterproof, it's only an "how to do" and can be improved!